# Is the paint() method called when a JFrame is created?

Tags: java, swing

I'm pretty new to GUI in java but the tutorial im using I understand everything until I go to this point:
 When I run this code I get frame with an oval(just like I wanted) BUT when is the paint method called?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Single Player");
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Game());
    }
}
```

Comment: The paint method is called every time the system tells it that it's state has changed and it needs to repaint. This is done by you in code by calling the method `repaint()`.

Comment: `but the tutorial im using` - if the tutorial recommends overriding paint() then get rid of the tutorial. Custom painting should be done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 4):

It's also called in the `setVisible(true)` method as can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/Component.java#Component.setVisible%28boolean%29)

Let me be more clear. I must admit I underestimated the number of calls to `paint(Graphics g)`. I know it's called by `repaint()` a lot and that normally this method should only makes sense after `setVisible(true)`. This is a rough estimation though and `repaint()` doesn't even call `paint(Graphics g)` directly.

This being said, you can always look up the call hierarchy of a method in your IDE (in Eclipse it's surely possible, I didn't try it on the other ones yet). To do this, you just need to call the method or overwrite it in a superclass e.g. the line `frame.paint(frame.getGraphics());` in your code would do (any method that you want to know where it's called) and you can select open call hierarchy from the pop-up menu to see every direct call and recursively see where the methods that call these methods are being called etc...

Answer (score 2):

Its invoked when swing has to draw components. You can use the breakpoint in eclipse debug mode to understand hows the code flow works. You can see the use of debug points in my image(bluedots on the left). In this part of the code you can find out that it is called in `setVisible()` method by putting a breakpoint next to it. Breakpoints are essential during GUI programming.

Example:

[image]

Reference:

As per the API documentation: Invoked by Swing to draw components. Applications should not invoke paint directly, but should instead use the repaint method to schedule the component for redrawing.

This method actually delegates the work of painting to three protected methods: paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren. They're called in the order listed to ensure that children appear on top of component itself. Generally speaking, the component and its children should not paint in the insets area allocated to the border. Subclasses can just override this method, as always. A subclass that just wants to specialize the UI (look and feel) delegate's paint method should just override paintComponent.

Answer (score 1):

Java automatically calls `paintComponent()` method, after the constructor.
You can manually call `repaint()` method inside another function/action depending what you want to do (if you want to draw something after).
Try to always call `super.paintComponent(g);` inside your paint() method.

Comment: 1-, you should never call super.paintComponent() for the paint() method. The proper way to do custom painting is to override the `paintComponent()` method and then you should invoke `super.paintComponent()` as the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

`paint()` method is called when you add `Game` class (which extends `JPanel`) to your `JFrame`. Because you are extending JPanel in Game Class. So `Game` class extends `JPanel` and this `JPanel` has a `paint()` method

So your `paint()` method is called in this statement.

```
frame.add(new Game());
```

The `paint()` is called when you want to draw something by yourself in the window. When you called that `paint()` method the window draws the items you defined in `paint()` method. So, your code in the `paint()` method shows two item in the window because you are trying to draw those two item in the `paint()` method

```
g2d.drawOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

Thus your `paint()` method draws an oval at position x=0 and y=0 point with 30 height and 30 wight and also after then your `paint()` method draws a filled oval at position  x=0 and y=0 with 30 height and 30 wight. Thus you can only visible the filled Oval (`fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);`) in your window which overlaps previous oval (`drawOval(0, 0, 30, 30);`).